# Multi-line ListView without third party component

Tags: c#, .net, listview

is there a way to enhance .NET ListView control to capable to show two line items? I couldn't use third party libraries.
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to enhance the buil-in in list view control.

have you thought about creating a 'user control'? that for sure will allow you to dream up your own list view that would allow for multi line.

Regards